Express tangent basis in embedding coordinates in order to calculate Killing vectors
I need help expressing vectors from the tangent basis in terms of others using a constraint that gives rise to a submanifold. Take Minkowski in 2+1 and the hyperboloid $-X_{0}^{2}+X_{1}^{2}+X_{2}^{2}=1$ (de Sitter in 2 dimensions). Take the embedding of global chart $X_{0}=senh(t)$, $X_{1}=cosh(t)cos \varphi$, $X_{2}=cosh(t) sen \varphi$ . Using the constraint properly we can express the new coordinates in terms of two $t=t(X_{1},X_{2})$, $\varphi=\varphi(X_{1},X_{2})$. Since i want to calculate the Killing vectors of de Sitter in terms of the new tangent basis $\{\partial_{t}, \partial_{\varphi}\}$ i want to express for example the boost $X_{1} \partial_{X_{0}} + X_{0} \partial_{X_{1}}$ (which is an obvious local symmetry that preserves the structure of the hyperboloid). My question is how do i write $\partial_{X_{0}}$ in terms of the partners $\partial_{X_{1}}$ and $\partial_{X_{2}}$ following the constraint in order to have an inversible set of equations?
The result i need to reach is $X_{1} \partial_{X_{0}} + X_{0} \partial_{X_{1}}= cos \varphi \partial_{t} - tanh(t) sen \varphi \partial_{\varphi}$
Disclaimer: i know that writing $\partial_{t}$ and $\partial_{\varphi}$ in terms of $\partial_{X_{0}}$, $\partial_{X_{1}}$ and $\partial_{X_{2}}$ works to construct the boost by equations of coefficients (for example, taking $cos \varphi \partial_{t} + A \partial_{\varphi}$ in order to cancel $X_{2}$ terms, etc) but i want to understand the previous in order to use it with more complicated examples.
